# Proof involving the Euler-Mascheroni Constant

Tags: real-analysis

a) Prove that for n $\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac {1}{k} \le \ln(n) \le \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}$$

b) Prove that the limit  $\gamma := \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n))$ exists.

Comment: So what parts can you do?  Given (a), can you prove (b)?  [also, are you sure the $\log(n)$ is inside the sum of part (b)?] Usually this proof uses a picture and $\int_{1}^n \frac{1}{t} dt = \log(n)$.

Comment: What confuses me is that we are not able to use picture proofs. I have no idea how to lay this problem out without the visual.

Comment: I would not be so concerned about that right now.  If you can draw the picture it will be good.  Please double-check your limit in part (b), I would expect the log to be outside the sum so that you can apply part (a).

Comment: Sorry about that. I am very new to MathJax.

Comment: A picture works well here. Draw $\ln$ and its representation as an integral and approximate.

Comment: Visually it makes sense, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to write this out...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\ln(n)=\int_{1}^n\frac{dx}{x}$. Try looking at upper and lower Riemann sums for this integral.

Edit: Behold, my terrible MS paint skills!
[image]

Comment: Looks like an equation typo needs fixing here.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the catch; must be getting sleepy :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\sum^n_{k=2} \frac 1 k = \sum^n_{k=2} \int^{k}_{k-1} \frac{dx}{k} \le \sum^n_{k=2} \int^k_{k-1}\frac{dx}{x} = \int^n_{1} \frac{dx}{x} = \ln (n).$$ Likewise $$\ln(n) = \int^n_{1} \frac{dx}{x} = \sum^{n-1}_{k=1} \int^{k+1}_k\frac{dx}{x} \le \sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\int^{k+1}_k\frac{dx}{k} = \sum^{n-1}_{k=1} \frac 1 k.$$

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

Use the result of part (a) to show that the sequence $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \log n$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$.

For part (b), note that $$\frac{1}{n+1} < \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x} = \log(n+1) - \log n,$$ implying

$$\frac{1}{n+1} - \log(n+1) < -\log n$$

Use this to show that $x_{n+1} < x_n$.

Since $(x_n)$ is bounded and decreasing you can conclude part (b).